# create thumbnail with Symfony or PHP

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, thumbnails

i use **sfThumbnailPlugin** for Symfony 1.4. I have problem... 
For example:

i set:

```
 $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(80, 100);
```

and if i upload image 700px/400px then this plugin make image 80px/40px instead of 80/100. If image is 400/700 this is ok. I know that be blurred.

How can i fix? Or how can i make in clear PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the docu or the constructor of the plugin :

```
/**
 * Thumbnail constructor
 *
 * @param int (optional) max width of thumbnail
 * @param int (optional) max height of thumbnail
 * @param boolean (optional) if true image scales
 * @param boolean (optional) if true inflate small images
 * @param string (optional) adapter class name
 * @param array (optional) adapter options
 */
public function __construct($maxWidth = null,
                            $maxHeight = null,
                            $scale = true,
                            $inflate = true,
                            $quality = 75,
                            $adapterClass = null,
                            $adapterOptions = array()
                           )
```

You need to modify your parameters like this e.g.

```
// so height will be calculated
$thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(80, null, true);
```

Comment: Sorry, but, i don't quite understand how the plugin would guess that he wants a 100px height. Will it calculate proportionally to the original size? How can I actually force making out of scale thumbnails?